# URLSearchParams GAS in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

If there is a possibility to implement such a construction in google apps script (html service) when placing the script in the iframe.

Or how to pass parameters from an external page to google apps script html in the input field of the input form.

Tried this design does not work.

domain.com/test?param1=abcd&param2=1234

`var params = new <code>URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));`
`var sendID = params.get("param1");`
`var sendemail = params.get("param2");`
`$("#name").val(param1);`
`$("#num").val(param2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can append the parameter to the script URL in the IFRAME tag as in this example.

```
https://script.google.com/.../exec?param1=value1&param2=value...
```

In your doGet method, you can access the parameter values as e.parmeter.param1, e.parameter.param2 and so on.

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  sendEmail(e.parameter.param1, e.parameter.param2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Is it possible to get parameters from the URL of the parent page?